# Sending parameters of selected values to controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have html like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
  <div>
    <p>Región</p>
    <select id="lstRegion" class="form-control  agenda_space" aria-hidden="true"></select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Solicitud</p>
    <select id="lstSolicitud" class="form-control agenda_space" aria-hidden="true"> </select>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div>
    <a href="javascript:;" id="event_add" class="btn green"> Actualizar Filtro </a>
    <br/>
  </div>
```

**JS:**

```
 $("#lstRegion")
                .getJSONCatalog({
                    onSuccess: function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    },
                    url: '/Agenda/GetRegion',
                    valueProperty: "ID",
                    textProperty: "valor"
                });
        //Load solicitud dropdown
        $("#lstSolicitud")
                .getJSONCatalog({
                    url: '/Agenda/GetSolicitud',
                    valueProperty: "ID",
                    textProperty: "solicitud"
                });
```

**Controller:**

```
 public ActionResult GetRegion()
        {
            try
            {
                var listaRegistros = db.CatalogoRegistros.Where(x => x.CatalogosCodigo == "REGI").Select(x => new
                {
                    x.ID
                     ,
                    valor = x.Valor
                });
                return Json(listaRegistros, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }


        }
        public ActionResult GetSolicitud()
        {
            try
            {
                var listasolicitud = db.Solicitudes.Select(x => new { x.ID, solicitud = "Folio: " + x.ID });
                return Json(listasolicitud, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }

        }
```

They work great I get my dropdwon lists very well, but now I want to do a GET action with selected values of each dropdown  when my   `<a href="javascript:;" id="event_add" class="btn green"> Actualizar Filtro </a>` it´s clicked.

But I´m really new in asp.net and I don´t know what I need to do to get selected values and send to controller.

As googling it I found I need to do method into my controller to get values so:

Controller will be:

```
  public ActionResult GetTareas(string lstRegionValue,  string lstsolicitudValue)
        {
        }
```

But I don´t know how to send them via JS, how can I do that to receive selected parameters into my controller? Regards

**UPDATE**
I try it using Ajax like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '@Url.Action("Agenda", "GetTareas")', 
    data: { region: $('#lstRegion option:selected').html(), solicitud: $('#lstSolicitud option:selected').html() }, // pass the value to the id parameter
    dataType: 'json', 
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }});
```

But how can I trigger that function when `event_add` is clicked?

Comment: Use getJSON (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) and pass the parameters in the "data". The functionality in your C# code will work in the same way, returning json

Comment: Can you check my update? @Simon

Comment: To call it wrap it in a function and call the function from the a href. I would also suggest putting the select values into variables (easier for debugging). you may want to get the value rather than the html from the select too.

Answer (score 0):

To run your updated ajax code on click, add `#event_add` click event handler and run your code inside it.

```
 $('#event_add').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); //suppress default behavior
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '@Url.Action("Agenda", "GetTareas")', // don't hard code your urls
    data: { region: $('#lstRegion option:selected').html(), solicitud: 
    $('#lstSolicitud option:selected').html() }, // pass the value to the id parameter
    dataType: 'json', // your returning a view, not json
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }});
});
```

Comment: I try it but I getting `http://localhost:50367/Gestion/@Url.Action(%22Agenda%22,%20%22GetTareas%22)?region=Norte&solicitud=Folio%3A+2` in chrome console why it occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Try the below updated code:

```
 $('#event_add').click(function(e){
   var regionval = $('#lstRegion option:selected').html(),
   var solicval =   $('#lstSolicitud option:selected').html(),

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '@Url.Action("Agenda", "GetTareas", new { lstRegionValue = regionval, lstsolicitudValue =solicval})', 
    });
});
```

Note : I didnt test the code, but hope that it should work for you

Controller code:

```
 public ActionResult GetTareas(string lstRegionValue,  string lstsolicitudValue)
        {
        }
```

Hope it helps , thanks